# C#, Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

How can I Split the following string using RegEx:

```
Product  :      Volks, Wagon      PurchasedDate: 16/09/2016    Quantity: 70    
IsVehicle: Y   Telephone: 9603 8303 (H) Your Reference :  111 Our Reference  
:   08512781112  Phone Enquiries:      Acct. Alan Donald
```

To Something Like:

```
Product: Volks, Wagon      
PurchasedDate: 16/09/2016    
Quantity: 70    
IsVehicle: Y   
Telephone: 9603 8303 (H)
Your Reference: 111 
Our Reference: 08512781112  
Phone Enquiries: Acct. Alan Donald
```

I tried something like this, but it did not produce my desired result:

```
var regexString = Regex.Split(textString, @"([a-zA-Z]*)[\r]*:([a-zA-Z]*)[\r]*");
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: It could be split by semicolon, but you have keywords with spaces. Will keywords always be as in this text?

Comment: Yeah. Same as in the text

Answer (score 2):

No pattern will be particularly readable because the input string is not regular (how to know which spaces are spaces and which are delimiters!?).

Keeping the pattern as generic and as simple as possible while accounting for these special cases, then:

pattern: `(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?:(?=Our|Your)|\s{2,}|$)`

replace:  `\1:\2\n`

https://regex101.com/r/rYkKkY/1/

Comment: Simpler than mine, obviously +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var s = "Product...";
string pattern =
    @"(?s)(\s+)(Product|PurchasedDate|Quantity|IsVehicle|" +
    @"Telephone|Your Reference|Our Reference|Phone Enquiries)(\s*?(\r\n)*?\s*?:)";
string s2 = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s, pattern, "\r\n$2:"), @"\u0020{2,}", "\u0020");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `(Product)\s*:\s*(\w+,\s*\w+)\s*(PurchasedDate)\s*:\s*(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s*(Quantity)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*(IsVehicle)\s*:\s*(Y|N)\s*(Telephone)\s*:\s*(\d+\s\d+\s\(\w\))\s*(Your Reference)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*(Our Reference)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*(Phone Enquiries)\s*:\s*(.+)`

**Substitution**: `$1:$2\n$3:$4\n$5:$6\n$7:$8\n$9:$10\n$11:$12\n$13:$14\n$15:$16`

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgIzI1/2)

Or you can use:

**Regex**: `(Product|PurchasedDate|Quantity|IsVehicle|Telephone|Your Reference|Our Reference|Phone Enquiries)\s*:\s*(\w+,\s\w+|\d+\/\d+\/\d+|(?:Y|N)|\d+\s\d+\s\(H\)|\d+|.+)\s*`

**Substitution**: `$1:$2\n`

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgIzI1/3)

Answer (score 0):

You could ***match*** it instead of splitting:

```
(?<key>\b(?:(?!\s{2,})[^:])+\b)\s*:\s*
(?<value>\b(?:(?!(?:Y?[Oo]ur\ Reference)|\s{2,})[^:])+\b)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8YkVPE/1).